# How to retrieve my voicemail messages to audio files?

Tags: samsung, backup, voicemail

I want to download a backup of my voicemail messages to mp3 (or any other audio format), but I don't know how to do so.

My scenario is the following:

I received several voicemail messages during the last few months, and now I want to download them for a personal backup.

My voicemail app (built-in from the factory. [Samsung galaxy A10](https://www.samsung.com/sg/smartphones/galaxy-a/galaxy-a10-black-32gb-sm-a105gzkgxsp/)) gives me the option to listen to these audios but does not give any option to download/archive/save/forward to these messages.

On my carrier website ([Orange in France](https://www.orange.fr/portail)), I'm able to retrieve (and download) only the last 15 days' messages. They keep the listened messages just for 14 days (30 days for the not listened ones).

I've tried to use third-party apps to download my messages (e.g., "voicemail saver" that is paid and "visual voice mail & missed call alert" that is free), but none of these apps worked to recover these messages.

My question is: since I can listen to these messages, I'm sure they are stored somewhere. So how can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the apps you have tried are working like call recorders, but as far as I know call recording no longer works on recent Android versions. On modern mobile networks everything is IP as well, but I don't think you can use that interface to access the voice messages this way, as this interface is not public and thus not accessible for you.

The only way to directly download those message is the web interface of your mobile network provider, but as you told us this way does not work.

As you have still access to the voicemail messages via phone the following two options are available:

1. Use your SIM card in an older Android phone (best Android 7 or older) and try a working call recorder app or one of your voicemail saver apps. On those older Android versions they should work.
2. Play back the voicemail on your phone and place a microphone next to the speaker to record it. The microphone can belong to a second smartphone, a PC or any different other (digital) recording device.

Comment: I'll probably go through the second option, but I'll also give a try to the first one. I didn't know these messages were directly related to the SIM card. I thought that they were stored in the built-in voicemail app

Comment: Can recording work if the device is rooted?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket If the call recorder supports using root for recording it should work. or you directly use the appropriate Magisk module: https://www.xda-developers.com/basic-call-recorder-magisk-module/

Comment: Thank you Robert.

Answer (score 1):

Could you physically save them in a analogous manner?

You know, record them with another device whilst playing them from your phone.